# Prove that a system of linear equations can’t have exactly two solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

I just want to verify with you all that my proof is valid.
Hypothesis of the proof are the following: Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $x_1,x_2$ are two solutions to the system $Ax = b$ where $b$ and x are vectors of $n$ entries. Then, prove that the system can’t have exactly 2 solutions *i.e.* : $x_1,x_2$.

What I did was basically express the line joining $x_1$ and $x_2$ points in vector parameter used form *i.e.*: $l(t) = x_1 + t(x_2-x_1)$ for $t$ real.Then you show that $$Al(t) = Ax_1 + tAx_2 - tAx_1 = b +tb-tb = b.$$ I’m sure there are numerous different approaches that one can take to prove it and I’ll be happy to read them but also to confirm mine is correct.

Comment: It is correct. More generally for every $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb R$ (I'm assuming you are working on $\mathbb R$), the vector $\lambda x_1 + \mu x_2$ is also a solution. That is one of the first motivation for the theory of linear algebra that I guess you will soon discover ?

Comment: @Zag Indeed, we better assume that the OP work on $\Bbb R$, or at least not on $\Bbb F_2$.

Comment: Zag- Thank you. From what your landa and mu is for you, landa must be equal to 1-mu right?

Comment: @Zag Your statement is false unless $b=0$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin wow indeed I don't know what I was yhinking there